# Issue with function inside route (Clojure/Compojure)

Tags: clojure, compojure

I am with a issue on use the following code inside a route.

```
(str "Size " (t/pay-billets-found)) ;-> "Size 2"
```

The (t/pay-billets-found) return a integer.

My routes code:

```
(defroutes app-routes
(POST "/upload" []
     {:message (str "a " (t/pay-billets-found))}))
```

With give me this:

```
    clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: clj-http: status 500
                    client.clj:171 clj-http.client/wrap-exceptions[fn]
                    client.clj:522 clj-http.client/wrap-accept[fn]
                    client.clj:536 clj-http.client/wrap-accept-encoding[fn]
                    client.clj:512 clj-http.client/wrap-content-type[fn]
                    client.clj:683 clj-http.client/wrap-form-params[fn]
                    client.clj:707 clj-http.client/wrap-nested-params[fn]
                    client.clj:624 clj-http.client/wrap-method[fn]
                   cookies.clj:121 clj-http.cookies/wrap-cookies[fn]
                      links.clj:50 clj-http.links/wrap-links[fn]
                    client.clj:726 clj-http.client/wrap-unknown-host[fn]
                    client.clj:847 clj-http.client/put
                   RestFn.java:439 clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke
                       core.clj:33 tbbrr.core/pay-billet
                       core.clj:58 tbbrr.core/pay-billets-found[fn]
                       core.clj:56 tbbrr.core/pay-billets-found[fn]
                   LazySeq.java:40 clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval
                   LazySeq.java:49 clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq
               ChunkedCons.java:59 clojure.lang.ChunkedCons.chunkedNext
                      core.clj:667 clojure.core/chunk-next
                 protocols.clj:101 clojure.core.protocols/fn
                  protocols.clj:19 clojure.core.protocols/fn[fn]
                  protocols.clj:31 clojure.core.protocols/seq-reduce
                  protocols.clj:54 clojure.core.protocols/fn
                  protocols.clj:13 clojure.core.protocols/fn[fn]
                     core.clj:6289 clojure.core/reduce
                     core.clj:6341 clojure.core/into
                       core.clj:56 tbbrr.core/pay-billets-found
                     server.clj:36 tbbrr.server/fn
                       core.clj:94 compojure.core/make-route[fn]
                       core.clj:40 compojure.core/if-route[fn]
                       core.clj:25 compojure.core/if-method[fn]
                      core.clj:107 compojure.core/routing[fn]
                     core.clj:2515 clojure.core/some
                      core.clj:107 compojure.core/routing
                   RestFn.java:139 clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo
                      core.clj:626 clojure.core/apply
                      core.clj:112 compojure.core/routes[fn]
             keyword_params.clj:32 ring.middleware.keyword-params/wrap-keyword-params[fn]
              nested_params.clj:75 ring.middleware.nested-params/wrap-nested-params[fn]
                     params.clj:58 ring.middleware.params/wrap-params[fn]
          multipart_params.clj:107 ring.middleware.multipart-params/wrap-multipart-params[fn]
                      flash.clj:31 ring.middleware.flash/wrap-flash[fn]
                    session.clj:85 ring.middleware.session/wrap-session[fn]
                      Var.java:379 clojure.lang.Var.invoke
                     reload.clj:18 ring.middleware.reload/wrap-reload[fn]
                 stacktrace.clj:17 ring.middleware.stacktrace/wrap-stacktrace-log[fn]
                 stacktrace.clj:80 ring.middleware.stacktrace/wrap-stacktrace-web[fn]
                      jetty.clj:18 ring.adapter.jetty/proxy-handler[fn]
                  (Unknown Source)        ring.adapter.jetty.proxy$org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler$ff19274a.handle
           HandlerWrapper.java:116 org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle
                   Server.java:359 org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle
   AbstractHttpConnection.java:483 org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest
   AbstractHttpConnection.java:920 org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete
   AbstractHttpConnection.java:982 org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete
               HttpParser.java:642 org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext
               HttpParser.java:235 org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable
       AsyncHttpConnection.java:82 org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle
    SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628 org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle
     SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52 org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run
         QueuedThreadPool.java:608 org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob
         QueuedThreadPool.java:543 org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run
                   Thread.java:744 java.lang.Thread.run
```

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like your exception is happening inside `pay-billets-found` (tbbrr.core). Can you share that code?

Comment: @DiegoBasch here the code: https://gist.github.com/edipofederle/3c6e6d87c38d7d31b108

Comment: You're calling `put` with two maps instead of one. What's the second map supposed to be? Anyway, take it out.

Comment: Sorry, I removed one map. But the issue continue the same.... Thanks

Comment: So are you sure your put call is working? The exception suggests it isn't. Can you try it manually from outside your app, or via curl to see if the problem is with the server that receives that call?

Comment: Yeah, the put working. I use it on repl... and via curl.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63736/discussion-between-elf-and-diego-basch).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're returning a map `{:message (str "a " (t/pay-billets-found))}`

So ring assumes you're creating a proper response object with status code and what-not.

If you want to return an `edn` you shoud instead do:

```
(pr-str {:message (str "a " (t/pay-billets-found))})
```

If you want to properly build a ring response, either set the status and body:

```
{:status 200 :body (pr-str {:message (str "a " (t/pay-billets-found))})}
```

Or use the [ring.util.response](http://mmcgrana.github.io/ring/ring.util.response.html) helper.